# Querying Rights/Permissions that a User/Group has in Tridion

Tags: 2013-sp1

While you can see what Users/Groups have Rights to Structure Groups and Permissions to Folders, how can we find out the reverse?

In other words, how can we list which Structure Groups and which Folders a User/Group has, along with their Rights/Permissions?

Comment: This is not something that is available OOB or using TOM .NET. Out of curiosity, what is the business case for this implementation? Are you trying to find issues with the existing implemented security model?

Comment: @Shiva We are asked to provide a _Security Access Profile_ for the system, where listings of users, groups, user/group to permissions, and user/group to rights are needed.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, I don’t think that is possible - you’re going to need to write a Core Service script to traverse every folder and structure group (across the whole Blueprint) and build up you’re own list.

Once you have this info, you could write an Events System tool to record any permission changes in these items to prevent you having to run the report again.

Probably not the answer you were after!

Answer (score 3):

I've written a script using the CoreService to traverse every folder and structure group across the whole BluePrint.

See https://github.com/TridionCommunity/tridion-ba-toolkit.

This includes the expected settings in the system to get the same authorization setup (or perhaps Security Access Profile, if you will).

However, it doesn't gather the information from a user and Group perspective.

For that, you could either use the outputted .csv file to check manually or adapt the approach to show the same data from a Group, rather than a hierarchical, perspective.

*Note that it's been a while since I wrote this and there may be a few shortcuts (hacks) that could have been written in a much cleaner way.*